# set base directory jade - gulp

Tags: gulp, pug

I'm trying to set include partials in an index page. eg.

```
   body
    include ../partials/m-header.jade
```

However within this partial there are other files such as

**m-header.jade**

```
img.show-lg-up(src='../assets/logo/logo-white.svg', alt=' Logo')
```

which I need to ensure always have absolute paths, or maybe create a variable which defines the base directory.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The paths inside of the included `m-header.jade` will always be relative to `m-header.jade`.

If you wish to define an include relative to the root directory of the templates folder, you can usually set a `basedir` option on your jade compiler which will allow you to do

```
body
  include /partials/m-header.jade
```

Assuming the `partials` directory is in the root of the jade `basedir`.